# Can't run multiple mongodb docker container with same shared volume

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I want to run two mongo docker containers with docker compose. The mongo containers have same shared volumes with the docker host. When I ran it with docker compose, only one mongo container is working meanwhile the other is shutting down because it said

> DBPathInUse: Unable to lock the lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock
>   (Unknown error). Another mongod instance is already running on the
>   /data/db directory, terminating

This is my docker compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
    image: fernandomaxwell/frontend
    ports:
     - "3007:3007"
    networks:
      main:
      database_frontend:

  backend:
    image: fernandomaxwell/backend
    ports:
     - "2007:2007"
    networks:
      main:
      database_backend:

  mongo_backend:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
     - "/var/lib/mongodb:/data/db"
    ports:
     - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      database_backend:

  mongo_frontend:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
     - "/var/lib/mongodb:/data/db"
    ports:
     - "27018:27017"
    networks:
      database_frontend:

networks:
  main:
  database_backend:
  database_frontend:
```

Any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is here:

> The mongo containers have same shared volumes with the docker host

You cannot run two mongo instances on the same data-directory. It would lead to data corruption and strange problems, so mongo-db explicitly prohibits doing that (see also [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/456558/is-it-possible-to-run-multiple-mongod-instances-on-a-single-set-of-database-file) question here)

Why do you want to do this? Normally you would provide two different volumes for your mongo instances like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
    image: fernandomaxwell/frontend
    ports:
     - "3007:3007"
    networks:
      main:
      database_frontend:

  backend:
    image: fernandomaxwell/backend
    ports:
     - "2007:2007"
    networks:
      main:
      database_backend:

  mongo_backend:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
     - "/var/lib/mongodb-back:/data/db"
    ports:
     - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      database_backend:

  mongo_frontend:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
     - "/var/lib/mongodb-front:/data/db"
    ports:
     - "27018:27017"
    networks:
      database_frontend:

networks:
  main:
  database_backend:
  database_frontend:
```

Additionally you should consider to use named volumes, instead of host-paths. Doing that you don't need to take care of creating the directories on the host before starting the compose-file. To use named volumes just change the volume declaration from `"/var/lib/mongodb-back:/data/db"` to `"mongodb-back:/data/db"`

Comment: Hmm, I need to do that because I already have mongo data in docker host and I want to use that data in my mongo service. If I use your suggestion and then try to access mongo from my mongo service, my database become empty.

Comment: Ok, well, I think in that case you should not define two different databases. If you share the data folder it effectively is only one database anyways. So just define a single mongo-db in your compose file and reference it in front and backend.

Comment: hmm ok, I get it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What to do when I want multiple instant having same data. So, when 1 fails, other one can store data. It can be done using replicaset, but why  not in this?