# Best management of a container cross dependency

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In one directory I  have a docker compose file which declares service appA and service mongoDB and declares that appA depends on mongoDB.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mongoDB:
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

  appA:
    image: appA_image # Replace with your actual appA image
    depends_on:
      - mongoDB
    environment:
      MONGODB_URI: mongodb://mongoDB:27017/mydatabase # Example environment variable for MongoDB connection

volumes:
  mongodb_data: # This volume is used to persist MongoDB data
```

In another directory I have another docker compose file which declares service appB and service mongoDB and that appB depends on mongoDB.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mongoDB:
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

  appB:
    image: appA_image # Replace with your actual appA image
    depends_on:
      - mongoDB
    environment:
      MONGODB_URI: mongodb://mongoDB:27017/mydatabase # Example environment variable for MongoDB connection

volumes:
  mongodb_data: # This volume is used to persist MongoDB data
```

Please note that the mongoDB instance is one and the same. appA feeds data into in (an ETL pipeline) and appB consumes it (a query API).

If by mistake I perform a docker compose down in one of the two directories:

```
/appA/docker compose down
```

according to the docker-compose-yml file declaration also the mongoDB container will be stopped, breaking the other app.

I need these apps and mongoDB to share a container network and use the service names as hostnames (as you can see from the mongoDB URI).

How do I best manage this?

Comment: As you've shown this, the two Compose files are independent: you do _not_ share a database container, or a volume, or a network between the projects.  Running `docker-compose down` in one project should not affect the other.  Having the two projects be independent like this is frequently a best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't run multiple database services on the same volume. See this answer: [Can't run multiple mongodb docker container with same shared volume](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52661055/22257868)

Either 1) use a single compose file, 2) a compose file for each service, or 3) deploy a separate database for each app service.

1 ) Single compose file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mongoDB:
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data:/data/db
  appA:
    image: appA_image
    depends_on:
      - mongoDB
    environment:
      MONGODB_URI: mongodb://mongoDB:27017/mydatabase
  appB:
    image: appB_image
    depends_on:
      - mongoDB
    environment:
      MONGODB_URI: mongodb://mongoDB:27017/mydatabase


volumes:
  mongodb_data:
```

2 ) Alternatively, you can also split each service into its own compose file and use a shared Docker network `mongo` (see [Adding default external network in docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58601290/adding-default-external-network-in-docker-compose)):

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mongoDB:
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data:/data/db
networks:
  mongo:
```

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  appA:
    image: appA_image
    environment:
      MONGODB_URI: mongodb://mongoDB:27017/mydatabase
networks:
  mongo:
    external: true
```

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  appB:
    image: appB_image
    environment:
      MONGODB_URI: mongodb://mongoDB:27017/mydatabase
networks:
  mongo:
    external: true
```

3 ) Separate db for each app service

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mongoDB:
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - app1_data:/data/db
  appA:
    image: appA_image
    depends_on:
      - mongoDB
    environment:
      MONGODB_URI: mongodb://mongoDB:27017/mydatabase
volumes:
  app1_data:
```

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mongoDB:
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - app2_data:/data/db
  appB:
    image: appB_image
    depends_on:
      - mongoDB
    environment:
      MONGODB_URI: mongodb://mongoDB:27017/mydatabase
volumes:
  app2_data:
```

Comment: Thank you @Sebastian. The Mongo DB must be the same instance for both apps. appA is an ETL that populates it and appB is a query application. So maybe this would be a problem for suggestion 3 ? Suggestion 1 loooks nice provied you take care of docker ocmpose down ONLYTHEWANTEDAPP, right?

Comment: For such a use case I would opt for a single compose file. Yes, you then can handle each service like `docker compose down appB`.